# Storing A vector of structs

Tags: c++, syntax, vector, struct, declaration

```
struct node{
double dat;
char oper;
node *left,*right;
}
vector <node> data;
vector <node> op;
```

Here I declare my node struct and Trying to store a vector of nodes. It's a simple Binary Tree node.
ERROR occurs when I declare vectors. It says:  "invalid declarator before data" and same when I declare op.
Would you please Explain where's my fault and how to take a vector of structs? 
:-) THANKS!!!

Comment: have you added semi-column in actual code?

Comment: Umm.. Sorry What a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you missed the semicolon after the structure decleration.

```
struct node{
double dat;
char oper;
node *left,*right;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node{
double dat;
char oper;
node *left,*right;
};
```

note the ;

Answer (score 0):

Probably somewhere else there might be a problem in your code. Same code (with proper headers, a semi-column after struct declaration etc) compiles for me in gcc and xlc++ (AIX).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    double dat;
    char oper;
    node *left,*right;
};

int main()
{
    vector <node> data;
    vector <node> op;
}
```